# Saving a file in Clear Case dynamic view from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, clearcase

I have a Clear Case VOB mapped on my Z: drive in Windows 7 and checked out 2 files. All the other files are shown as read only in Visual Studio 2013 but these checked out files seem to be editable (no lock symbol like on the others), but when I try to save the file it only allows shows a "Save As" dialog and when I try to overwrite the file I get a message "Access to 'Z:...\khmwdkwdmx.d0c' is denied" (which I suppose must be some kind of generated temp file, because every time I try to save it always has a different name). If I edit the file in Notepad++ it can be saved as normal, no errors in that case.

Additional info: The problem seems to be that as I can't create new files in a clear case dynamic view only change the files I have checked out, so VS cannot create it's temp files while saving (like m4s1c0nk.swt, jl0lb2ob.255 and other random generated ones) so the file saving always fails. Is there any possible way to turn these file generations off or to generate them somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure of the state of the files within the parent folder of `Z:\...\khmwdkwdmx`, to check if those two files are indeed checked out.

Second, verify is there is no other processes keeping an handle of those files, preventing Visual Studio to update the actual files.

You can also fall back to a Visual Studio session opening your view using the full path of the dynamic view (`M:\MyView\MyVob\...`) instead of the subst `Z:\MyVob`

---

> The problem seems to be that as I can't create new files in a clear case dynamic view only change the files I have checked out,

Check if you can at least check out the parent folder, or check is associated right:

```
 cleartool descr -l parentfolder@@
```

(the @@ are for describing the element, not the version, of the parent folder).
Try a:

```
 cleartool protect -chmod 777 parentfolder
```

More generally, write issues are described in "[About the error Checked out version, but could not copy data to `<some-file.txt>` in view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146571)", and are following "[About ClearCase permissions on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21143292)".

Comment: As I checked the files are indeed checked out, I can check them in or undo the checkout on them. 
I tried restarting the system and then opening it only with VS but still the same error with no other possible handler process.
Tried opening it from the M drive but the same error occurred.

Comment: @LordGamez so it seems to be a limitations of Visual Studio regarding the management of those files.

Comment: @LordGamez following your edit, I have edited my answer to add more leads.